# Retrofit Kotlin and getting an Array?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Anyone here can give me a small hand with Retrofit? I am trying to get an Array from PHP.
This is my Response in Kotlin:

```
class QuestionnairesResponse (val status: Boolean, val message:String, val questionnaires: List<Questionnaire>)
```

Questionnaire class:

```
data class Questionnaire(
        val id: Int,
        val title: String,
        val questions: List<Question>
)
```

Question class:

```
data class Question (
    val id: Int,
    val text: String
)
```

My JSON array output:

```
{
   "questionnaires":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "title":"Are you hungry?",
         "questions":{
            "id":"1",
            "text":"How is your passion? "
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "title":"How are you feeling?",
         "questions":{
            "id":"1",
            "text":"How is your passion? "
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"5",
         "title":"Is testing working?",
         "questions":{
            "id":"4",
            "text":"How is the testing?"
         }
      }
   ],
   "status":true,
   "message":"Succefully got questionnaires!!!"
}
```

However, it seems it doesn't get the 'questions' part and it results in a failure. The strange thing is that If I change it to 'question' instead of 'questions' it doesn't result in a failure, and it gets the questionnaire details as ID and title, but stil; the question array is empty.

What is going wrong here? I can't seem to find the problem.

UPDATE: My backend needs to be fixed as questions need to be an array.
I just can't seem to wrap my head around on how to fix this issue when getting the data from MySQL....

My PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT questionnaires.id QuestionnaireId, questionnaires.title QuestionnaireTitle, questions.id QuestionId, questions.text Question 
FROM questionnaires INNER JOIN questionnaireshasquestions qa ON qa.idQuestionnaire = questionnaires.id 
INNER JOIN questions ON questions.id = qa.idQuestion";
$conn=$dbh->prepare($sql);

 
$conn->execute();

$result = $conn->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($row = $conn->fetchAll()) {

    $endResult['questionnaires']= $row;
    
}
//echo json_encode($endResult);
$idd = null;
$test = [];

foreach ($endResult['questionnaires'] as $questionnaire) {
        if ($idd != $questionnaire[0]) {
            $idd = $questionnaire[0];
            
            $test['questionnaires'][] = [
            'id'        => $questionnaire[0],
            'title'     => $questionnaire[1],
            'questions' => [
                    'id'   => $questionnaire[2],
                    'text' => $questionnaire[3]
                    ]
        ];
        }
}
```

One questionnaire can have multiple questions.

Comment: You have an object in each `questions` of your response instead of an array. If the response is correct, replace `val questions: List<Question>` with `val questions: Question`

Comment: But let's say one Questionnaire has 2 or more Questions. Then wouldn't it need to be ```val questions: List<Question>```?

Comment: And even if at the moment a Questionnaire has one question, I would still like it to be an array as some Questionnaires will have multiple questions. 
I hope I am clear :)
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Your backend is sending data in wrong format if you want `questions` to be an array. You will need to fix the backend code first

Comment: I updated the thread, hereby you can see my backend code... how can I correct this? So that I can collect multiple questions for each questionnaire? Thank you so much.

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP but I think you need to put `{ }` inside your `[ ]` in `questions`. And inside `{ }` put the id and text.